# CentOS 7 / Apache 2.4 / FastCGI Configuration

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, centos7, mod-fastcgi

Does anyone know how to properly configure PHP/FastCGI on a CentOS 7 machine using Apache 2.4?

In the Apache Virtual Host config file, I have this:

```
 <FilesMatch \.php$> 
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000" 
</FilesMatch>
```

It works but only for files ending in .php
(I can access the control panel but not the website)

The CMS outputs pages without any extensions and I get an "Access Denied." error when I access a page.

The pages (CMS templates) don't contain php code but they seem to be affected by this. How can I make sure, this also works for pages without any extensions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What extensions are you trying to make this work for?

Comment: for urls without any extensions. the cms I um using creates clean urls with  out any extensions but they're basically html files.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll have to do is set up an actual PHP page first. For instance, Wordpress uses a single `index.php` and then uses a mod_rewrite rule to redirect all traffic there. So all you see are clean URLs but it's still a PHP file with a PHP extension running the whole show.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess) talks about how to point all your URLs to a single PHP file. Remember that you can do this in both `.htaccess` as well as your Apache configs.